# jQuery .animate easing issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having trouble with the .animate function in jQuery and mixing it with easing.

The following works;

```
$("#PanelOne").mouseover(function() {
        $("#PanelTwo").stop(true, false).animate({ marginLeft: "420px"}, 150 );

});
```

But this doesn't;

```
$("#PanelOne").mouseover(function() {
        $("#PanelTwo").stop(true, false).animate({ marginLeft: "420px"}, 150, 'easeOutQuint' );

});
```

I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong, it's going to be something blindingly obvious, but I've never used easing or jQueryUI before, so I'm pretty lost!

EDIT: I'm referencing jQueryUI here;

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js

Comment: Did you include the effects in jquery ui? http://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: From the docs: "The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default, called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called linear. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins, most notably the jQuery UI suite."

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/4vCjn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work just fine.

Make sure you've download jQuery-UI with this effect included. Check this under Effects here: http://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: Yes, I see now how this would help!

Comment: I was referencing the library from Google, but must have had the wrong address, I'm not referencing it from jQueryui.com and it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have My Code Match With Yours, Hope It Will Be Helpfull For U..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  div { background:yellow; border:1px solid #AAA; width:80px; height:80px; margin:0 5px; float:left; }
  div.colored { background:green; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="PanelOne"><img src="http://www.clipartguide.com/_small/0808-0710-1516-1324.jpg" width="85px" height="81px"></div>
  <div id="mover"><img src="http://www.alissweettreats.com/i//Smiley_Face.jpg" width="85px" height="81px"></div>
  <div><img src="download2.jpg" width="85px" height="81px"></div>
<script>

    $("#run").click(function(){
      $("div:animated").toggleClass("colored");
    });
    function animateIt() {
      $("#mover").slideToggle("slow", animateIt);
    }
    animateIt();

    $("#PanelOne").mouseover(function() {
    alert('Its Working');
        $("#mover").stop(true, false).animate({ marginLeft: "420px"}, 150, "easeOutQuint" );
        });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```